# Como retornar o location correto para route com resources no singular?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ao utilizar o nome da controller no singular, a rota é prefixada com `_index` ao final do nome da rota (ex. `dispute_conference_index`). Dentro da controller no método `create` o parâmetro `location` em `render` recebe a URL do registro.

Infelizmente o nome passado para `location` é `dispute_conference_url` ao invés de `dispute_conference_index`.

Veja abaixo a configuração de rota que estou usando:

```
resources :disputes, shallow: true do
  scope module: :dispute do
    resources :conference, except: :index
  end
end
```

Veja os detalhes de routes:

```
                 Prefix Verb    URI Pattern                                Controller#Action
conferences              GET    /conferences(.:format)                     conferences#index {:format=>:json}
dispute_conference_index POST   /disputes/:dispute_id/conference(.:format) dispute/conference#create {:format=>:json}
conference               GET    /conference/:id(.:format)                  dispute/conference#show {:format=>:json}
                         PATCH  /conference/:id(.:format)                  dispute/conference#update {:format=>:json}
                         PUT    /conference/:id(.:format)                  dispute/conference#update {:format=>:json}
                         DELETE /conference/:id(.:format)                  dispute/conference#destroy {:format=>:json}
                         PUT    /conference/:id/start(.:format)            dispute/conference#start {:format=>:json}
                         PUT    /conference/:id/cancel(.:format)           dispute/conference#cancel {:format=>:json}
                         PUT    /conference/:id/finish(.:format)           dispute/conference#finish {:format=>:json}
```

Qual a forma correta de corrigir está questão, passando o `location` correto?

---

**Corrigindo a pergunta**: O motivo do erro é por conta do parâmetro `shallow: true`, ele altera o `path` das rotas fazendo com que seja necessário uma intervenção manual ou através de uma função (url_path).

Ao tentar rodar o método `create` será obtido um erro pois não será possível encontrar a `location`.

Comment: Adicionar estaticamente não é uma boa ideia... `location: :dispute_conference_index`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de varias tentativas e erros a solução pareceu. Primeiro deve ser movido `shallow: true` para a chamada de `resources` e por fim deve ser adicionado o atributo `shallow_prefix: :dispute`. Veja abaixo como fica:

```
resources :disputes do
  scope module: :dispute, except: :index do
    resources :conference, shallow: true, shallow_prefix: :dispute
  end
end
```

Feito isso `routes` será montado da forma desejada:

```
Prefix Verb         URI Pattern Controller#Action
conferences              GET    /conferences(.:format)                     conferences#index {:format=>:json}
dispute_conference_index POST   /disputes/:dispute_id/conference(.:format) dispute/conference#create {:format=>:json}
dispute_conference       GET    /conference/:id(.:format)                  dispute/conference#show {:format=>:json}
                         PATCH  /conference/:id(.:format)                  dispute/conference#update {:format=>:json}
                         PUT    /conference/:id(.:format)                  dispute/conference#update {:format=>:json}
                         DELETE /conference/:id(.:format)                  dispute/conference#destroy {:format=>:json}
                         PUT    /conference/:id/start(.:format)            dispute/conference#start {:format=>:json}
                         PUT    /conference/:id/cancel(.:format)           dispute/conference#cancel {:format=>:json}
                         PUT    /conference/:id/finish(.:format)           dispute/conference#finish {:format=>:json}
```

Perceba que minha controller está montada no modulo `dispute` isso também está relacionado ao problema.